# throw FileNotFoundException is not working

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, throws

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Exercise3_2
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;

   double score1, score2, score3, score4, score5;
   double avg;

   Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("test.txt"));

   PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter ("testavg.out");

   firstName = inFile.next();
   lastName = inFile.next();

   outFile.println("Student name : " + firstName + " " + lastName);

   score1 = inFile.nextDouble();
   score2 = inFile.nextDouble();
   score3 = inFile.nextDouble();
   score4 = inFile.nextDouble();

   outFile.println("Test scores: " + score1 + " ," + score2 + " ," + score3
                                   + " ," + score4);

   avg = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4) / 4;

   outFile.printf("Average test scores: %5.2f %n, avg");

   inFile.close();
   outFile.close();

   }
}
```

Whenever I run this this is what I get : 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

......WHY!!!!

Comment: Try providing a full path to "test.txt".

Comment: try to put `Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("test.txt"));` statement in try block.

Comment: You are throwing the exception from the main method, so it is not caught by any catch block anywhere, so try to put  'Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("test.txt"));' statement in try block and catch exception immediately by catch statement.

Comment: When I put 'Scanner inFile...' anywhere else it tells me the inFile for firstName and lastName could not be found. I have also tried a direct path. I feel like I might have a misunderstanding of the whole I/O with file method. Thank you for all the help guys!

Comment: Am I supposed to just create a folder somewhere on my Disk Drive or what?

Comment: Put this statement just before the Scanner call :   System.out.println( "CWD......................["+System.getProperty("user.dir")+"]");  It prints out what your Current Working Directory is...Then check that directory and see if test.txt is there.